# Applying CSS style to the last element on the right?

Tags: jquery, css

I use this code to remove the margin of the third element (the thumbnails):

```
$j('.project:nth-child(3n)').addClass('odd-element');
```

[image]

I started to use media queries to make the site mobile ready but I got this problem:

[image]

When the screen stretches, the class no longer needs to be applied to the third element but to the second element:

Is there any way of modify the jQuery code above to say something like: apply the class tot he last element on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to do this with JS, no mater what?

I would do it like this:

```
.project { float:left;margin-left:20px }
.projectParent { margin-left:-20px }
```

There you go. Instead of adding right margins, just add left margins and move the container few px to the left.

No js involved!

// edit: oh, yeah, and you get rid of all flexible box issues!

Comment: +1 would do it exactly the same (maybe with position:relative, but that's irelevant)

Comment: @Ionut Staicu Can you give me an example? Because I tried it and the whole container (including the `.project` divs move to the left.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something along the lines of this:

```
$j(function() {

    if($j(window).width() < 500) {

        $j('.project').removeClass('odd-element');
        $j('.project:nth-of-type(2n)').addClass('odd-element');

    });

});
```

Comment: Try it without the 'j's after each '$'

Comment: @Brogrammer - sorry, didn't notice that in the original question - fair point!

Answer (score 1):

Why not handle this the 'dumb' way and use this algorithm:

1. Loop through all the relevant elements
2. Based on their position, work out which are the furthest-right
3. Add the class to those elements

E.g.

```
$(function() {
    var max = 0;

    $('li').each(function() {
        max = $(this).offset().left > max ? $(this).offset().left : max;
    });

    $('li').each(function() {    
        if ($(this).offset().left == max)
        {
            // add your class here - this is just an example
            // for the purposes of demo'ing
            $(this).css('margin-left', 0);
        }
    });
});
```

See
http://jsfiddle.net/S9TpX/1/

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way but my instinct would be to look at your main column width, divide by project (item) width, this will tell you how many items per row, you can then feed that value into your nth selector.

Can't really show any code without seeing your page structure.